# shrink Window title bar

Tags: settings, release-juno, pantheon

Is there a way to shrink all Window title bars on Juno?

I've tried making changes to `gtk.css` and `app.css` with no luck.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Install** `dconf`:

```
sudo apt install dconf-tools
```

**Open** it from the menu and then goto `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor`

[image]

, and **set** it to `1.44` or `1.5` on a 4k screen.

*Everything looks very nice on a 4k screen now*

Comment: Please mark your answer as **answer** and let others know that this is solution of your problem.