# Juno with multiple hires monitors

Tags: display, xorg

I have a work computer with two 4k monitors and one 2k. I currently have to use Wayland with Ubuntu to get all the monitors to work. With Xorg I could only ever use two of the monitors. Not an expert with xrandr yet.

Is there a way to use all three monitors with Elementary OS? The video card is an Intel HD 630.

thank you

Comment: Not an answer but this might help: Try with the Live version of elementary OS, maybe there's a solution trying settings. The good thing is if you break something just reboot and try again.

Comment: Yeah, tried that. I end up with a partial view of the desktop in the upper left 1/5 of a corner on the main 4k screen. 

If I go into setting I do see all three monitors detected correctly.

When I was playing with this on Ubuntu Xorg, I was seeing the same issue but the login screen spanned all three monitors correctly. Problem only occurred after login.

Comment: check this.... might help https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17744/14940

Comment: Thanks, but, that's a different issue I opened and found the answer to when trying to get one 4k screen, my laptop, to scale the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get the multip display with two 4k and one 2k monitor to work by:

```
1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
2. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will upgrade Mesa to the latest version.

Since I was using an Intel HD 630 GPU I also did the below:

In `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` create the file `20-intel.conf` with the below contents.

```
 Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
 EndSection
```

Not completely sure if the `20-intel.conf` file is needed. But my multi-hdpi monitor setup is now working perfectly.

Comment: The `20-intel.conf` is required for all this to work on my desktop.